# Proving a derived set $A'$ is equal to the closure of the derived set $\bar{A}'$

Tags: general-topology

I have been asked to prove that a derived set is equal to the closure of the derived set for every subset $A$ of $X$, where $X$ is an infinite set with the cofinite topology.

I have been directed to consider two separate cases: one where $A$ is finite, and the other where $A$ is infinite.

Comment: Try to show that in the first case the derived set is empty, and in the second case it is equal to $X$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be an infinite set equipped with the cofinite topology. That is $U\subseteq X$ is open iff $X\setminus U$ is finite. Recall that for $B\subseteq X$ the derived set, $B^{\prime}$, is equal to the set of limit points of $B$.

We wish to show that if $A=B^{\prime}$ for some $B$ then the closure of $A$, $cl(A)$, is equal to $A$ itself. That is, we want to show that every derived set is closed. Before showing this let's examine just what closed sets look like in this topology.

If $A\subseteq X$ is any finite set (derived or otherwise) then $X\setminus A$ is infinite and therefore open. Thus $A$ is closed and $cl(A)=A$. Alternatively, $A$ is infinite. Then if $x\notin A$ and $U\subseteq X$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$, then $X\setminus U$ is finite, so $U\cap A$ must be infinite. We then have that $cl(A)=X$. In particular, if $B\subset X$ is infinite, then $B^{\prime}=X$.

Having established that, we begin with your claim. Let $A=B^{\prime}$ be given. We consider two cases. If $B$ is finite, say $B=\{x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\}$ then $B$ is closed and $B^{\prime}=\emptyset$. Why is it empty? Because, if $x\in X\setminus B$ then $U=X\setminus B$ is an open set containing $x$ that is disjoint from $B$. If $x\in B$, say $x=x_{i}$ then $U=X\setminus\{x_{1},\ldots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\ldots,x_{n}\}$ is an open neighbourhood of $x_{i}$ such that $U\cap (B\setminus\{x_{i}\})=\emptyset$. Thus, no point of $X$ is a limit point of $B$, so $B^{\prime}=\emptyset$. We then have $cl(A)=cl(B^{\prime})=cl(\emptyset)=\emptyset=A$.

Alternatively $B$ is infinite. Then, as we discussed $cl(B)=X$, and in particular $B^{\prime}=X$. Then $cl(A)=cl(B^{\prime})=cl(X)=X=A$.

As those are the only two cases, we have that all derived sets in this space are closed.